# How to do something like $this->data[$variable] in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

Right now I have this in my code:

```
$this->data['products'] = $this->$mdl->get_objs_by_category($cat);
```

but I want to be able to do something like to be easier to maintain:

```
$objs = 'products';

$this->data[$objs] = $this->$mdl->get_objs_by_category($cat);
```

But `$this->data[$objs]` seems not to be working. Is this even possible in PHP. If yes, what is the right wiring of it?

Comment: Shouldn't this already work? Have you tried? What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: FOr some reason this is working `$this->data[$this->objs]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you gave is perfect valid PHP code, I assume that you only gave us an excerpt and not your whole code. Nobody is able to help you in this case. From your comment above I assume you have something like the following.

```
<?php

class Foo {

  public $data;

  public $objs = "products";

  public function fn() {
    $this->data[$this->objs] = $this->mdl->get_objs_by_category($cat);
  }

}
```

This code makes sense with your question and your comment and there is nothing to answer, it's simply perfect valid object oriented PHP code that is working as it should and as it is described in the official and any other PHP manual.